# Possible to mix mongodb gorm and regular java

Tags: mongodb, grails-orm, micronaut

I'm new to micronaut, I've used spring extensively. I like the GORM style of mapping entities but not keen on using groovy for everything on this new project. Is it possible to use groovy for my entities for gorm and the service + DAO's with java?

Comment: what especially on gorm are you missing? and why use a schema on a more or less schemaless database in favor to using some sql based relational database with jpa, hibernate and micronaut data?

Comment: I'm not missing anything per say. I am writing the entities with groovy but would prefer to use the java lang. for the rest of the development

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use groovy for my entities for gorm and the service
> and DAO's with java?

If you are writing your own DAO's, then the answer is yes.

**NOTE:** Be aware that GORM Data Services in particular (http://gorm.grails.org/7.0.4/hibernate/manual/index.html#dataServices) have to be written in Groovy because their generation relies on Groovy AST transformations.  We do not provide support for writing those in Java.